# Pygame - drawing lines. Traced path of double pendulum is being drawn over by the pendulum itself - how do I prevent this?

Tags: python

I want to create a double pendulum which has the path of the second mass traced in red. In order to give the illusion of the pendulum moving, I am redrawing the previous position of the pendulum in white (the same color as the background). However, drawing the pendulum draws over parts of the red traced line leaving it discontinuous and patchy. How can I give the illusion of the pendulum moving whilst drawing the path the second mass takes without it being drawn over?

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
start_x = 400
start_y = 250

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
Display.fill(white)

pygame.display.set_caption('Double Pendulum')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def game_loop():
    crashed = False
    length = 150
    length2 = 100
    mass = 8
    mass2 = 3
    theta = math.pi
    theta_v = 0
    theta2 = math.pi-0.0001
    theta2_v = 0
    damping = 0.002
    g = 1
    x = length*math.sin(theta)
    y = length*math.cos(theta)
    x2 = length2*math.sin(theta2)
    y2 = length2*math.cos(theta2)
    xp = length*math.sin(theta)
    yp = length*math.cos(theta)
    x2p = length2*math.sin(theta2)
    y2p = length2*math.cos(theta2)
    last_position1 = None
    last_position2 = None

    while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True
            print(event)

        theta_a = (((-g*(2*mass+mass2)*math.sin(theta))-(mass2*g*math.sin(theta-2*theta2))-(2*math.sin(theta-theta2)*mass2*((theta2_v**2)*length2 + (theta_v**2)*length*math.cos(theta-theta2))))/(length*(2*mass+mass2-mass2*math.cos(2*theta-2*theta2))))-(damping*theta_v)
        theta2_a = ((((2*math.sin(theta-theta2))*(((theta_v**2)*length*(mass+mass2))+(g*(mass+mass2)*math.cos(theta))+((theta2_v**2)*length2*mass2*math.cos(theta-theta2)))))/(length2*(2*mass+mass2-mass2*math.cos(2*theta-2*theta2)))) - (damping*theta2_v)

        theta_v += theta_a
        theta2_v += theta2_a
        theta += theta_v
        theta2 += theta2_v

        x = length*math.sin(theta)
        y = length*math.cos(theta)
        x2 = length2*math.sin(theta2)
        y2 = length2*math.cos(theta2)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, white, (start_x,start_y), (start_x+xp, start_y+yp), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, white, (start_x + int(xp),start_y + int(yp)), mass, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, white, (start_x+xp, start_y+yp), (start_x+xp+x2p, start_y+yp+y2p), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, white, (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p)), mass2, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, black, (start_x,start_y), (start_x+x, start_y+y), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, black, (start_x + int(x),start_y + int(y)), mass, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, black, (start_x+x, start_y+y), (start_x+x+x2, start_y+y+y2), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, black, (start_x + int(x) + int(x2),start_y + int(y) + int(y2)), mass2, 0)

        if last_position2 is not None:
            pygame.draw.line(Display, red, last_position2, (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p)), 1)
        last_position2 = (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p))

        xp = x
        yp = y
        x2p = x2
        y2p = y2

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

SOLVED!
I found a solution to my problem. I created a completely transparent surface and drew the red traced path onto that transparent surface. I then used blit to superimpose the traced path onto the display.

```
background = pygame.Surface([800,500], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
background = background.convert_alpha()

if last_position2 is not None:
     pygame.draw.line(background, red, last_position2, (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p)), 1)
last_position2 = (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p))

Display.blit(background,(0,0))
```

Comment: Hey, can you get the code running in https://repl.it/languages/pygame? Also, I think the overwriting problem can be solved by using another surface that is of the same size as the display. You can draw you line overlay onto that surface and blit it to screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love the double pendulum. Thank you for sharing. So to avoid redrawing on the trace lines, you can draw them on a different surface and blit the surface to the display (main surface). See below. I've commented where I added the changes.

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
start_x = 400
start_y = 250

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
Display.fill(white)
# Add surface
Surface = pygame.Surface((800,500))
Surface.fill(white)

pygame.display.set_caption('Double Pendulum')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def game_loop():
    crashed = False
    length = 150
    length2 = 100
    mass = 8
    mass2 = 3
    theta = math.pi
    theta_v = 0
    theta2 = math.pi-0.0001
    theta2_v = 0
    damping = 0.002
    g = 1
    x = length*math.sin(theta)
    y = length*math.cos(theta)
    x2 = length2*math.sin(theta2)
    y2 = length2*math.cos(theta2)
    xp = length*math.sin(theta)
    yp = length*math.cos(theta)
    x2p = length2*math.sin(theta2)
    y2p = length2*math.cos(theta2)
    last_position1 = None
    last_position2 = None

    while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True
            print(event)

        theta_a = (((-g*(2*mass+mass2)*math.sin(theta))-(mass2*g*math.sin(theta-2*theta2))-(2*math.sin(theta-theta2)*mass2*((theta2_v**2)*length2 + (theta_v**2)*length*math.cos(theta-theta2))))/(length*(2*mass+mass2-mass2*math.cos(2*theta-2*theta2))))-(damping*theta_v)
        theta2_a = ((((2*math.sin(theta-theta2))*(((theta_v**2)*length*(mass+mass2))+(g*(mass+mass2)*math.cos(theta))+((theta2_v**2)*length2*mass2*math.cos(theta-theta2)))))/(length2*(2*mass+mass2-mass2*math.cos(2*theta-2*theta2)))) - (damping*theta2_v)

        theta_v += theta_a
        theta2_v += theta2_a
        theta += theta_v
        theta2 += theta2_v

        x = length*math.sin(theta)
        y = length*math.cos(theta)
        x2 = length2*math.sin(theta2)
        y2 = length2*math.cos(theta2)

        if last_position2 is not None:
            #draw on surface
            pygame.draw.line(Surface, red, last_position2, (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p)), 3)
            #blit surface to display (main surface)
            Display.blit(Surface,((0,0)) )
        last_position2 = (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p))

        pygame.draw.line(Display, white, (start_x,start_y), (start_x+xp, start_y+yp), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, white, (start_x + int(xp),start_y + int(yp)), mass, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, white, (start_x+xp, start_y+yp), (start_x+xp+x2p, start_y+yp+y2p), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, white, (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p)), mass2, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, black, (start_x,start_y), (start_x+x, start_y+y), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, black, (start_x + int(x),start_y + int(y)), mass, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(Display, black, (start_x+x, start_y+y), (start_x+x+x2, start_y+y+y2), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(Display, black, (start_x + int(x) + int(x2),start_y + int(y) + int(y2)), mass2, 0)

        if last_position2 is not None:
            pygame.draw.line(Display, red, last_position2, (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p)), 1)
        last_position2 = (start_x + int(xp) + int(x2p),start_y + int(yp) + int(y2p))

        xp = x
        yp = y
        x2p = x2
        y2p = y2

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```